# cant insert date to mysql DB from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, format

I'm using c sharp and mysql.
when i'm trying to insert a date from DateTime type to date column in DB all i get is `0000-00-00`

i'm parsing my DateTime like this : `sessionDate.ToShortDateString()`

but getting empty date ...

any help please

Comment: is the DB column Date or DateTime type?

Comment: What DB are you using and how are you entering the DateTime into the DB, show some more specific code.

Comment: You need to post more of your code on how you do the insert, but without any context it does look odd to convert a datetime to a string when the targetcolumn is date

Comment: the column is in a type of "Date"
the insert is by "insert to DB query" where i'm sending a string of sessionDate.ToShortDateString() to the date column

Comment: eddy - if i'm not parsing my date in c# then i'll send full date time to DB , aka "8/19/2011 12:00:00 AM" by parsing it i send "8/19/2011" instead, but mySql Date expecting "2001-08-19"...
i also tried to "tostring it" by using "YYYY-MM-DD" format, but then i got an exception from DB

Comment: wihtout real code - firstly i'll say use DateTime as your db column type, and secondly don't use the ToString method on your DateTime object just stick it in as it is

Comment: dormisher - that's the first thing i did, but then i'm getting an exception...

Comment: unfortunately i cant switch columns type in DB at this moment...

Answer (score 1):

MySql uses date in yyyy-MM-dd format,So U can overide the toString() method  Of DateTime.Now  property.

```
YourDate= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: it doesnt work, i get an exception : "Incorrect date value: '1984' for column 'sessionDate' at row 1" and  i've no idea why 1984 is there... the date i'm insert is current date...

Comment: Can You Post the Entire Code.. Will look at it. did u tried using BreakPoints to Explore the values???

Answer (score 0):

Try this to format your date time to a string value that is acceptable to MySQL

String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", sessionDate);

Comment: didnt work
i'm getting next exception from DB :

Incorrect date value: '1984' for column 'sessionDate' at row 1...

i've no idea why 1984 is there... the date i'm insert is current date...

Comment: I think we'll probably need a larger snippet of your code.  Its difficult to tell where the error is coming from by just looking at this little information.  Can you give the table definition and also the entire block of code which you are using to try and insert the date in the database?